# How to get specific column from database and work with this data in a datagridview using Entity Framework?

Tags: c#, database, winforms, entity-framework, datagridview

I have 8 tables in my database. When I choose one of them and show data in datagridview using Entity Framework, I get columns with navigation properties. How can I hide these columns?

For example, `Electrolyte` table code:

```
public partial class Electrolyte
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Electrolyte()
    {
        this.Experiment = new HashSet<Experiment>();
    }

    public short Electrolyte_ID { get; set; }
    public string Electrolyte_Name { get; set; }
    public string Formula { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Component_Content { get; set; }
    public Nullable<double> Thermal_Conductivity { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<Experiment> Experiment { get; set; }
}
```

I tried to use this code, but then I can't add and delete data via datagridview:

```
var query = from c in con.Electrolyte
            select new
                   {
                       Electrolyte_ID = c.Electrolyte_ID,
                       Electrolyte_Name = c.Electrolyte_Name,
                       Component_Content = c.Component_Content,
                       Formula = c.Formula,
                       Thermal_Conductivity = c.Thermal_Conductivity
                   };

BindingSource source = new BindingSource();
source.DataSource = query.ToList();
tableView.DataSource = source;
```

How to view specific columns and work with database via datagridview at the same time?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can hide them:

```
tableView.Columns["Electrolyte"].Visible = 
tableView.Columns["User"].Visible =
tableView.Columns["Machine"].Visible = 
tableView.Columns["Material"].Visible = false;
```